# Migrate a regular SVN repo into a trunk-branches-tags folder structure

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a regular svn repo with this folder structure:

```
conf
dav
db
hooks
locks
```

How can I migrate it into the

```
trunk
branches
tags
```

structure without losing my history?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got two things confused. The first is the *representational* of the repository. The second is how the repository is *physically* structured. No matter what you do, your repository will always have that *physical* structure.

To really understand your question, you need to show us the *representational* structure. To do that, run the following command:

```
 $ svn ls $REPO
```

Where `$REPO` is your repository's root URL. For example, how do you checkout a project? Like this?

```
$ svn checkout http://svn.firstvegibankcorp.com/svn/project
```

Then `$REPO` will be `http://svn.firstvegibankcorp.com/svn`.

Fortunately, you can always use `svn mv` to move things around. I'll append the exact commands to my answer, but I don't know your current layout.

### Assuming no, `branches`, `tags`, and `trunk` directories at all

Let's say people simply checked in files without the setup:

```
$ shop -s extglob                         # Assuming BASH. No need to do this with Kornshell
$ svn co --depth=immediates $REPO workdir # Checks out first level of the directories
# cd workdir
$ svn mkdir trunk                         # Create the "trunk" directory
$ svn mv !(trunk) trunk                   # Moves all files and directories to under trunk
# svn mkdir branches tags                 # Make the rest of the structure
$ svn commit -m"Creating basic directory structure.  # That's it!
```

The other way is to do a dump and load of your *physical* repository. You take your repository down, create a dump, then create a new version with a load. You can specify the `--parent-dir` parameter:

```
$ ssh $SVN_REPO_SYSTEM
$ cd /opt/svn_repos
$ svnadmin create new_repo
$ svnadmin dump repo | svnadmin load --parent-dir trunk new_repo
```

This will take a dump of your *physical* repository, then immediately load it in to a new repository. All history and revisions will be preserved. However, instead of being in the root of the repository *representational* structure, they will be under the `trunk` directory. Users will have to use `svn switch` to switch the URL of their local working directory to match the new repository structure.

Comment: One plus of the second method is that future use of svndumpfilter may be easier.  When things move about it'd difficult to filter.  I also wanted to point out that in the above sample you can keep the same repo name (though they cannot ever exist in the same dir)

Comment: It's not necessary to check out anything to do this structural changes. All can be done inside the repository.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you confuse two very different things:

- content of SVN repository
- the way SVN repository is stored on disk

To see content of SVN repository you should use some kind of client. Examples: svn.exe (command-line client), TortoiseSVN (GUI client with integration into Windows Explorer). trunk-branches-tags convention is for repository content.

On disk SVN is usually stored as a set of files and folders (conf, dav, ...), but you should not touch them, SVN will manage that structure. And this structure has no relation to the structure of content.

Comment: Thanks. My question was really about how to migrate my repo to the trunk-branches-tags convention. Currently there is none of that convention done. It was a plain repo created by svnadmin create.

Comment: @kakyo: As I see from your question you already have some history in the repository. Do you expect everything in the root to become the new trunk?

Comment: Yes. Everything should be in the trunk while keeping their relative paths for now. But I wish I can keep all the history.

Comment: @kakyo: was going to respond, but answer of Dawid W. seems to cover everything needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let your repository be `http://svn.atyourserver/` with the above subfolders.

Make a `svn mkdir http://svn.atyourserver/trunk` to create a new folder (you may have to use also the `-m`-Parameter for a comment).

Do this also for branches and tags.

Then do a `svn move http://svn.atyourserver/conf http://svn.atyourserver/trunk`. This will move folder (or file) `conf` to folder `trunk`, preserving the history because everything is inside the subversion repository.

Do this also for your other folders/files.

Comment: svn mkdir seemed to have succeeded but I don't see the trunk/branches/tags folder right away on the repo side. Then when I svn move I got "svn: E160013: '/svn/myrepo/!svn/rvr/440/conf' path not found", although conf folder is available at the source.

Comment: Please show me the command you executed, than I can tell you who the move command has to look like.

Comment: I got it. I shouldn't be moving on the server side. It should be all done on client side and then checked in.